# Unable to use Postgres VER_15_5 using AWS CDDK python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, postgresql-15

While trying to upgrade minor version AWS Aurora Postgres from 15.3 to 15.5, I am getting below error.

```
AttributeError: type object 'AuroraPostgresEngineVersion' has no attribute 'VER_15_5'. Did you mean: 'VER_10_5'?
```

CDK version: 2.99

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was added in CDK version `2.118` in [this commit](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/commit/9d8b06f6478a98e01e3aaa86c1dbf22d6e861f05)

You can use it in an earlier version directly:

```
AuroraPostgresEngineVersion.of('15.5', '15', { s3Import: true, s3Export: true });
```